# How to Get the word Randomely of a string from select area php

Tags: php

I want to show A massage with some random text 
My massage is
`text {text1|text2} Text3 {text4|text5}`

and  result Will be

Result = `text text2 Text3 text5`

`{text1|text2} And  {text4|text5}` always random Output.

I already try with this
`$text= 'text {text1|text2|}' ;`
`preg_match_all("/{(.*?)}/", $text, $matches);`
`$var1=$matches[1][0];`
`$a = explode('|', $var1, -1) ;`
`$rand= array_rand($a);`
`$randome= $a[$rand];`
`echo $randome;`

But There is two Problem i face ,

- {text1|text2|} << There need one Extra " | "
- I want to add more like text {text1|text2|} text {text3|text4|} text {text5|text6|}

Is here any simple Solution for that ??

Comment: Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i know bro . but i tried for write this code  . but i didn't success :(

Comment: That doesn't make your question ok :( Post your code and explain what problem you are having with it. What happens and what should happen

Comment: You need a random generator function such as `rand` or `mt_rand`, post your sample and if it doesn't work we'll help you

Comment: Edited . Please Check !!

Answer (score 0):

Approaching this with regular expressions is bad. Instead compose your string once you have extracted a random string from an array:

```
$words1 = array('text1', 'text2');
$words2 = array('text4', 'text5');
$rand1 = array_rand($words1);
$rand2 = array_rand($words2);
$string = 'text ' . $words1[$rand1] . ' text3 ' . $words2[$rand2];
echo $string;
```

Comment: Result is `text 0 text3 1`

Comment: Sorry now it works array_rand only returns an index of the array